# Print a thunder-bolt like pattern

Tags: c++

I recently came across this question in an interview wherein I had to print a pattern. The pattern looked trivial, but I could not figure out the solution. Please help me identify the mistake with my code.

Below are the test cases:

```
n = 1
x


n = 2
 x
x x
 x


n = 3
  x
   x
x o x
 x
  x


n = 5
    x
     x
    o x
     o x
x o x o x
 x o
  x o
   x
    x


n = 10
         x
          x
         o x
          o x
         x o x
          x o x
         o x o x
          o x o x
         x o x o x
x o x o x x o x o x
 x o x o x
  x o x o
   x o x o
    x o x
     x o x
      x o
       x o
        x
         x
```

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string reverse(string s) {
  int start = 0, end = s.size()-1;
  while(start<end) {
    char temp = s[start];
    s[start] = s[end];
    s[end] = temp;
    ++start;
    --end;
  }
  return s;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int count=0;
  string s = "X";
  bool wasLastX = true;
  for (int i=1;i<=n-1;++i) {
    for(int j=1;j<=n-1;++j) {
      cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
    if (i == n-1) {
      break;
    }
    if (s[0] == 'X' || s[0] == 'O') {
      s.insert(s.begin(), ' ');
    }
    else {
      if (wasLastX) {
        s.insert(s.begin(), 'O');
        wasLastX = false;
      }
      else {
        s.insert(s.begin(), 'X');
        wasLastX = true;
      }
    }
    ++count;
  }

  string temp = s;
  if (n%2 == 0) {
    cout<<s<<" "<<s<<endl;
  }
  else {
    if (s[1] == 'X') {
      s.insert(s.begin(), 'O');
    }
    else if (s[1] == 'O') {
      s.insert(s.begin(), 'X');
    }
    cout<<reverse(temp)<<s<<endl;
  }

  int count1 = 0;
  for (int i=1;i<=n-1;++i) {
    cout<<" ";
    for(int j=1;j<=count1;++j) {
      cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    temp.pop_back();
    ++count1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

First I print the upper half, then from the upper half that was generated, for the lower part, I reverse it and print it again.

Here is my output:

```
n = 1
xx

n = 3
  X
   X
X O X
  X

n = 5
    X
     X
    O X
     O X
X O X O X
  O X
   O
    O
```

However, the code works fine for n = 2 and n = 10. But again, for n = 4, it shows wrong output. So, I cannot generalize that it is not working for only odd values of n.
For n = 4, I get this, which is wrong as all the elements after middle row should begin with x and mine is beginning with o.

```
   X
    X
   O X
O X O X
 O X
  O
   O
```

Comment: Please show your attempt/code

Comment: @GhostCat I have added my attempt as well. Please check once.

Comment: @GBlodgett, please check the attempt made my me.

Comment: My bad that I did not add my attempt here in the first go itself. Apologies.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat for the constructive feedback. My question looks much better now. I'll keep these points in mind from now on.

Comment: You are welcome. It is always nice to work with people who actually listen and then act accordingly.

Comment: Question now re-opened. Thank you for the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because initially a `[java]` tag was attached to this question, I gave it a shot at implementing it using java code. Hope this help in building for logic for c-code

```
public class ThunderBoltPattern {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 5;
    int evenOddFactor = (input % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1; // If it is even, add 1 else it should be 0
    // length on pattern based on input
    int length = input * 2 - evenOddFactor;

    // Using character array to store individual character at various point
    char[][] array = new char[length][length];
    int factor = 0;

    while (factor < input) {
        for (int i = 0 + factor, j = input - 1; i < input; i++, j++) {
            array[i][j] = 'x';
            array[j][i] = 'x';
        }
        for (int i = 2 + factor, j = input - 1; i < input; i++, j++) {
            array[i][j] = 'o';
            array[j][i] = 'o';
        }
         // Because character are repeated on same line after 4 digit, using 4 as factor
        factor += 4;
    }

    for (char[] chs : array) {
        for (char ch : chs) {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I cannot follow the complicated logic you have developed to solve the problem.  Here's a quite simple code that solves your problem.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/* its important the next string is symmetrical */
string s1 = "x o x";
string s2 = "     ";

int main()
{
    int n, i, l = s1.size();

    cin >> n;
    while (n > l) {
        s1 += s1.substr(1, l-1);
        s2 += s2.substr(1, l-1);
        l = 2*l - 1;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << s2.substr(0, n-1)
             << s1.substr(l - i, l)
             << endl;
    }
    cout << s1.substr(0, n - 1)
         << s1.substr(l - n, n)
         << endl;
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << s2.substr(0, i)
             << s1.substr(0, n - i)
             << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very simple and easy to understand. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Abhinav, see my edit to get on how to simply get it to handle larger and larger values of `n`.